# UIScrollView with multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, sdk

i have one scrollview and 4 UIviewcontrollers with xib files now i want to add 4 viewcontrollers to scrollview

and also the scroll is enabled for four viewcontrollers

any one know this plz answer this problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add them. What's the problem?

```
// this loads a view controller from a nib
controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibsName" bundle:nil];

// this adds the viewcontroller's view to the scrollview
[scrollView addSubview:controller.view];

// place the subview somewhere in the scrollview
CGRect frame = controller.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 600;
controller.view.frame = frame;

// don't forget to release the viewcontroller somewhere in your dealloc
[controller release];
```

Do this for all your four controllers.

Comment: but the scroll is not enabled that four viewcontrollers plz tell me how to handle this scrolling property within that four viewcontrollers

Comment: you need to make the contentView of the scroll view big enough to contain all four views. just do ` scrollView.contentSize = <a size big enough to layout your views>; `

Comment: This appears to work to add the UIViewController to the UIScrollView, but it seems like the UIViewController's delegate methods aren't called. I'm not seeing any data in my table view in the UIViewController subclass - do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: You're abusing ViewControllers... http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can just add the views of the viewcontrollers to your scrolling view, but remember that you are rolling your own equivalent to a UITabBarController or UINavigationController and so you have some responsibilities:

When you alloc init your vc from a nib the vc will get its viewDidLoad method called.

But when you put the vc.view into your scrollview YOU need to call [vc viewDidAppear:YES] (and also call viewWillAppear just before if your vc uses it).

Be careful with things like presenting modal view controllers from your vc as this may not work as you expect.

Peter

Comment: Saw ur answer when got in similar problem, as you have suggested I am taking care of viewDidAppear:YES and viewWillAppear, but presenting  views is giving me absurd results, any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

I realize that it's quite an old question. But now you can use `UIPageViewController`.