# Scrolled-menu UIComponenet in ios

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i want to build a scrolled-menu uicomponent like the image given below.could u guys help me which is the best place to start.Am i supposed to  use a toolbar with button embedded with scroll? any help is much appreciated..
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `UIScrollView` with your buttons as subviews. Forget about using `UIToolbar` because that would make things very complicated (You can use an image to imitate the appearance of the toolbar).

Just make a `UIScrollView`, add your buttons as subviews, and remember to set  the `contentSize` according with the number of buttons you have (numButtons*buttonWidth).

That's my approach, but maybe there's another good/elegant solution.

[Here](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd-v4/) you'll find a PSD that will help imitating the toolbar.

Comment: thanks man..i ve created an view controller using uiscrollview with buttons ..everything works fine the problem is if i m to click one of the button its takes me to a next view..wat i want is that the scroll bar to be fixed and the change of view got to get affected below the scrollview on the click of the corresponding buttons..any idea

Comment: You can do that in different ways. You can use a scrollview that contains all the views that the user can navigate, and when the user push a button scroll it to the associated view. Another approach is adding and removing the views whenever the user push a button

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any sample here but look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977283/uiscrollview-with-multiple-uiviewcontrollers/4977296#4977296) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990658/how-do-i-put-viewcontrollers-into-a-uiscrollview/1990847#1990847) They cover what you need